# Navigation Menu JQuery Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two problems:

1. Regarding the "detected" css class, if you click another list element before the animation which displays the element's drop-down contents has completed, the element's dropdown contents will appear, however, the wrong list element will be highlighted. This is my attempt at creating what is known as an "active" class to clarify which list element's dropdown contents are being displayed. How do I ensure that whichever list element is highlighted/selected, the correct dropdown contents are displayed?
2. Upon the initial loading of the page, or refreshing, a list element and its dropdown contents are highlighted and displayed although the user has not selected them. How do I ensure that upon loading the page, no list element or its dropdown contents are displayed until a list element is clicked?

Thank you.

```js
$(function() {
 $('#nav .nav-ul li').on('click', function () {
   //control selected nav li's css
   var $detected = $(this).closest('.nav-ul');
    $detected.find('li.detected').removeClass('detected');
    $(this).addClass('detected');
        
   //figure out which rel to show
    var ulToShow = $(this).attr('rel');
    
    //hide current rel
    $('.substitute .sub-child.active').hide(416, function() {
     $(this).removeClass('active');
     $('#'+ulToShow).fadeIn(528, function() {
       $(this).addClass('active');
        
      
      });
    });
    
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#nav {
  background-color: /*blue*/;
  float: right;
}
#nav .nav-ul {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  background-color: /*yellow*/;
  border-left: solid 2px #000000;
  border-right: solid 2px #000000;
  /*transform: skewX(-20deg);*/
}
#nav .nav-ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px;
  /*transform: skewX(20deg);*/
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
}
#nav .nav-ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #E51D27;
}
#nav .nav-ul li.detected {
  color: #E51D27;
}

#nav .substitute {
  float: right;
  background-color: /*pink*/;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
#nav .substitute .sub-child {
  float: left;
  display: none;
}
#nav .substitute .sub-child.active {
  display: block;
}


#nav .substitute .sub-child ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#nav .substitute .sub-child ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul class="nav-ul">
    <li class="detected" rel="pay1">Color</li>
    <li rel="pay2">Shape</li>
    <li rel="pay3">Size</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="substitute">
    <div id="pay1" class="sub-child active">
      <ul>
        <li>Red</li>
        <li>Blue</li>
        <li>Green</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pay2" class="sub-child">
      <ul>
        <li>Square</li>
        <li>Circle</li>
        <li>Triangle</li>
        <li>Diamond</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="pay3" class="sub-child">
      <ul>
        <li>Small</li>
        <li>Medium</li>
        <li>Large</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many ways to do it. I chose the JQuery way since you already are using it. For the first problem, I simply removed the click handler on the links while your animation was working, and added it back once the animation completed. This way, there is no effect of intermediate clicks when the animation is running. There could be other ways to do it, but thats the concept I usually use to enable/disable items when I have animations running.

For the second problem, I removed the `active` and the `detected` classes from the initial DOM and added logic to check if there is nothing active then only run the fade in animation, otherwise run both fade out and fade in.

There is some duplicity in the code, so I would recommend creating functions and refactoring this, but it should give you the idea.

Seems to be working fine. Updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/bm7qoe3k/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: For the second problem, when you click one list element and then click another one rapidly, the content from one list element gets appended to end of the selected element. Barring that issue, it appears you fixed the original issue.

Comment: @DanielJohnson see updated fiddle above in the answer or here: https://jsfiddle.net/bm7qoe3k/1/

Comment: Gotcha, I think I'm understanding what you did - I'll look over it more to figure it out. Last question,  how I would I add that in the event of a click off of the nav menu, the dropdown content would retract, and the highlighted elements would go unhighlighted?

Comment: @DanielJohnson If I understand you correctly, you want to simulate an off animation of an already selected nav item. You would need to detect if the click is somehow on the same item as the selected item and then only run the animation for deselection. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for steering me in the right direction.